# Prove or disprove $|x+y+z|\ge\sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z\in R$, such $|x|\neq|y|\neq|z|$,and $|x|,|y|,|z|>1$ and $xy+yz+xz=-1$
prove or disprove
$$|x+y+z|\ge\sqrt{3}$$

I try

$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\ge 0$$
so $$|x+y+z|^2\ge 3(xy+yz+xz)=-3$$
why?

Comment: Take $x=1+\epsilon$, $y=1+2\epsilon$ and $z = \frac{-1-xy}{x+y} = -1 - \epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3)$ then $xy+yz+zx = -1$ and $|x+y+z| = 1 + 3\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$ so any value larger than $1$ is possible. As in the now deleted answer you can prove that $|x+y+z| > 1$ always holds.

Comment: The inequality fails for $x=-y=z=1$ so by continuity it will also fail in a small enough neighborhood thereof where $|x|,|y|,|z|$ are strictly $>1$.

Answer (score -1):

Counterexample:

Suppose $x = 1.02, y = -1.0001, z = \frac {-1-xy}{x+y} = \frac {0.020102}{0.0199} \approx 1.01015$

$|x|,|y|,|z| > 1$
and
$xy + yz + xz = -1$
and $|x+y+z| = 1.03 < \sqrt 3$

Since $|x|, |y|, |z| > 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 3$

$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(xy + xz + yz) \ge 0\\
(x+y+z)^2 \ge 3 -2 \ge 0\\
(x+y+z)^2 \ge 1\\
|x+y+z| \ge 1$

Comment: I didn't downvote and I am just commenting to understand something from your answer that isn't clear to me. Can you explain how the third equation (from the last) implies the second (again from the last)?

Comment: You are right, I really chunked it up...

Comment: @user170039 this is better